# Gallio Icarus vs. Testdriven.net

Tags: tdd, gallio, testdriven.net

What are the differences between using a VS integrated tool like Testdriven.net or using a GUI test runner like Icarus or NUnit GUI?

What do you prefer and why?

So far i've found that reports are better in Icarus than in td.net, which only features a commandline output.
However td.net is faster to use, i can execute single tests more easily without having to uncheck the rest first. NCover integration is very nice also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Icarus has one great feature that keeps me using it.  It is the automatic reload and rerun of tests.

I keep Icarus hovering over on the left hand monitor.  Each time I build in Visual Studio, Icarus reloads the assemblies and runs all the tests.  It's sort of like the instant feedback of Resharper's Solution Analysis, except for tests instead of syntax.  Running the tests is automatic and doesn't seem to affect the performance of Visual Studio (likely b/c Icarus is it's own process, not hosted inside the IDE).

To enable this configuration go to Icarus->Options->Test Explorer.  Check 'Always reload files' and 'Run tests after reload'.

Comment: Yes i do also Digg that. Alas my question wether td.Net provides any benefit.

Comment: In defense of TD.Net, build runs as part of running unit tests, in place, and without taking up screen real-estate.

Comment: What would be really cool is a feature to re-run relevant unit tests as you edit code in Visual Studio.  But then how do you define "relevant?"

Comment: This is an old question but since I found it looking for a good test runner integrated with Visual Studio, it's worth mentioning [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net) does exactly what GregC says: "re-run RELEVANT unit tests as you edit code in VisualStudio"

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a Continuous Integration server (like a build server, but runs unit tests)?

If so, you can set up gallio to run your unit tests and have all the reporting information there while allowing the developers to use something with faster feedback while they are working.

If there is no option, I prefer something that is integrated into the IDE like Testdrvien. The immediate feedback is really helpful when refactoring a piece of code or developing something new under TDD. Besides, if you don't have the sanity checking going on at a single point (like a CI server), you are going to want as many eyes as you can find on those unit tests. Developers tend to use whatever is easiest and, generally, an integrated test suite is easier than a separate component.

Comment: i am an individual developer, so using a ci server is not nescessary for me. Actually i _do_ have one, hovewer im just using it for metrics and the like (and for fun of course)

Comment: @Johannes Rudolph If a CI server is overkill, you could still have build scripts. Rake is really easy to set up and run from the command line whenever you would want metrics. Here is the resource I started with for Rake. http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2008/11/4/getting-started-with-rake-on-net/